# Image Slider with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I have some trouble with this image slider. I got seven images and I try to make them move when I'm hovering and a zoom out effect when i stay over them.

Please give me some adivice to make it work.

```css
.slide-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 65, 108), rgb(255, 75, 43));
}

.image-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: .7s;
}

.slides-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 370px;
  transition: .5s;
  filter: saturate(10%);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  height: 370px;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#slider-span1:target~.image-slider #img1,
#slider-span1:target~.image-slider #button-1 {
  width: 380px;
  height: 585px;
  background-color: transparent;
  filter: saturate(100%);
}

/*for each 7 slider-span- */

.slider-span1:target.image-slider {
  left: 70%;
}

.slider-span2:target .image-slider {
  left: 50%;
}

.slider-span3:target .image-slider {
  left: 25%;
}

.slider-span5:target .image-slider {
  left: -25%;
}

.slider-span6:target .image-slider {
  left: -50%;
}

.slider-span7:target .image-slider {
  left: -70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span1"></span>

  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span2"></span>

  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span3"></span>

  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span4"></span>

  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span5"></span>

  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span6"></span>

  <span class="slider-span" id="slider-span7"></span>

  <div class="image-slider">
    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-1">
      <img src="/poze/img1.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img1">
      <a href="#slider-span1" class="button" id="button-1"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-2">
      <img src="poze/img2.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img2">
      <a href="#slider-span2" class="button" id="button-2"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-3">
      <img src="poze/img3.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img3">
      <a href="#slider-span3" class="button" id="button-3"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-4">
      <img src="poze/img4.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img4">
      <a href="#slider-span4" class="button" id="button-4"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-5">
      <img src="poze/img5.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img5">
      <a href="#slider-span5" class="button" id="button-5"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-6">
      <img src="poze/img6.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img6">
      <a href="#slider-span6" class="button" id="button-6"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides-div" id="slide-7">
      <img src="poze/img7.jpg" alt="" class="img" id="img7">
      <a href="#slider-span7" class="button" id="button-7"></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And another problem, but not so important as this, is that when I pass over an image, the color does not appear and had to do that.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's the difference between "hover" and "stay over"?

Comment: Do you have the link to the source you copied because it looks like it's copied wrong.